# Can't install Filezilla, can't locate package

Tags: apt, lubuntu, filezilla

I run `sudo apt-get install filezilla` on Lubuntu but it comes back saying it can't locate the package. Specifically `E: Unable to locate package filezilla3`

I've tried updating, clearing, and updating again, but it can't find it. Haven't been able to find anyone else with this problem. FileZilla says to try using the package manager to get Filezilla. I tried their binary, but it asks for me to choose something to run it. I do get a few lines during an apt-get update that say it can't initiate connection.

Oh and I tried ./filezilla with the binary, it said file not found.

I am using version 19.04 of Lubuntu.

Output of apt-get update

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.23), connection timed out Could not connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.26), connection timed out
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.23), connection timed out Could not connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.26), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: • Your version of Lubuntu is … ? • Instead of "I do get a few lines during an apt-get update" provide actual output. • And do you have the universe repository enabled?

Comment: Lubuntu version is most recent. Adding output now.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=filezilla   (most recent I assume is 19.04; but please be specific as many people see 18.04 (3rd most recent) as the most recent as they only count LTS releases...)  If you can't work out your issue, posting `apt-cache policy filezilla` may help us to help you, verify your source (current, out-of-date mirror etc)

Comment: apt-cache policy filezilla comes back with `N: Unable to locate package filezilla`

Comment: Well this LOOKS like your system has no IPv6 upport and that's resulting in NOT getting updates right.  Do you have an IPv6 address or no?  You may need to force IPv4 for APT by default

Comment: I have seen quite a few IPv6 apt failures lately.

Comment: `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update`

Comment: That must've been the case. I was trying it on a campus internet connection. At a different place and its working now. I'll try it on campus next time with that command and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had problem on home network, special thanks to comments for solution: `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update`

Forces IPv4 for apt-get.